# Can I wear a Tish Bekishe

Tags: minhag

I like the look of Tish Bekishes, and my family comes from chassidim but we are not chassidish. My question is, do I have to have the minhag of wearing Bekishes in order to or can I just buy one and wear it?

Comment: No one is gonna stop you. You don't need anyone's permission.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Avishai and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

I have a number of non-chassidic rebbes (from Ner Israel in Baltimore) who wear tish bekishes for comfort at the Shabbos meals, so go ahead and enjoy it.